# ¿Como integrar el login de Google a mi página web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, google-signin

Tengo mi credencial de google y mis html

[image]

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="452754398500-biqbijrhbgevv2s60ngsg59kjtc4kdhj.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**panel.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="452754398500-biqbijrhbgevv2s60ngsg59kjtc4kdhj.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
   <script>
    function signOut() {
     var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
     auth2.signOut().then(function () {
       console.log('User signed out.');
     });
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

el problema es que no se como deba de funcionar eso
no me redirige hacia panel.html solo carga el pop up y se cierra y me muestra el log con los datos de la cuenta

Comment: Si te muestra los datos de la cuenta significa que funciona correctamente, si te refieres a que no tienes que seleccionar una cuenta igual es por que ya tienes la sesion iniciada con una sola cuenta y utiliza esa de forma automatica

Answer (score 1):

al llamar el sdk debes de hacerlo llamando la función onLoad de esta manera

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
```

en el archivo panel.html debes agregar la inicialización de gapi.auth2 para que te funcione correctamente, de esta manera:

```
function signOut() {
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
auth2.signOut().then(function () {
//redirecciona a donde quieras cuando cierra sesión por ej. índex.html que es donde iniciaste sesión
    window.location.href = "index.html";
});
//Esta función es la que te está faltando
function onLoad() {
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.auth2.init();
});
```

Así podrás hacer que el usuario cierre sesión de google en tu web

Answer (score -2):

En la parte de codigo donde te muestra datos en la consola, es ahi donde debes agregar una redireccion como es javascript seria algo como window.location.replace("panel.html");
y por seguridad deberias quitar los logs, google te lo da en el ejemplo, pero es solo eso, ejemplo.  yo tengo problemas con el logout en cambio u_u

Comment: Deberías leer [answer], para mejorar tu respuesta